# Асинхронная загрузка картинок в адаптере RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-asynctask

Есть RecyclerView, у каждого пункта списка есть картинка. Картинка загружается асинхронно с помощью AsyncTask внутри холдера. Проблема в том, что когда список очень большой и пользователь быстро его прокручивает, то запускается единовременно очень много экземпляров AsyncTask, что может приводить к OutOfMemoryError.
Как можно обойти это?
Знаю, что существуют Picasso и UIL, но в данном случае они не подходят.

Comment: АсинкТаск - устарел. UIL тоже устарел и не поддерживается уже несколько лет. Пикассо тоже, можно сказать устарел и есть его улучшенный аналог `Glide`. Используйте его. Пилить велосипеды для рядовой задачи используя устаревшие инструменты - зачем?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Нужно избежать добавления еще одной библиотеки. Поэтому нужно свое решение. Можете подсказать реализацию?

Comment: Всё же я настаиваю на том, что в этом случае обязательно надо использовать библиотеку. Но, раз уж вам очень хочется сделать неправильно и поиметь проблем на ровном месте, то можно попробовать добавлять экземпляры Асинктасков в Лист и, в случае, если его размер больше некоторой величины при добавлении новой таски вызывать сancel() на тех, что в начале списка. Работать это будет плохо и медленно, но работать может (наверное). Может у вас проблема не в этом вовсе а в превышении лимита в 65 тыщ методов в проекте и именно потому либы не хотите добавлять? Поясните подробнее почему не хотите либы,плз

Comment: @ЮрийСПБ, Избегаю добавления дополнительной библиотеки по двум причинам: во-первых, мой проект - это библиотека и в случае изменения сторонней либы у пользователя могут быть конфликты версий или иные проблемы. Во-вторых, насколько знаю, эти библиотеки не умеют получать превью с видео.Метод cancel() у AsyncTask не очень хорошо работает по моему опыту. В принципе, AsyncTask можно заменить и другим решением, главное получить асинхронность на выходе и возможность апдейта в UI-потоке.

Comment: Такие популярные либы как Glide всегда следят за обратной совместимостью. Проблем возникнуть не должно. К тому же всегда можно проапдейтить свою либу, либо использовать конкретную либу (её версию) в своей - она сама не обновится и проблем не будет. Glide умеет в превью для видео. В случае если видео находится на девайсе. Можно даже [время видео выбрать](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766885/). А все и всяческие настройки и оптимизации в Glide сделаны и проверены тысячами кодеров. Без либ вы нормально делать будете не один месяц и в итоге придёте к полному копированию либ.

Comment: Ну это до тех пор пока разработчик сторонней библиотеки не решит выпустить версию 4.0 и переделать совсем все :) Такое бывает ведь и с серьёзными библиотеками. Опять-таки, неизвестно, будет ли у меня возможность в тот момент обновить свою библиотеку. А хочется, чтобы пользователи могли её использовать как можно дольше вне зависимости от меня. Может бы было бы удобно использовать стороннюю библиотеку через рефлексию, чтобы в случае чего, просто отключить этот функционал...

Comment: Проверяйте скорость пролистывания, если скорость высока, то не подгружайте картинки. Создайте ограничение на загрузку картинок не чаще чем 2 в сек. Вообще полностью согласен с ЮриемСПб лучше используйте библиотеку иначе что-то подсказывает что все же  будут проблемы.

Comment: @BArtWell, вы можете в своей либе подключить стороннюю либу как jar файл - так она никогда не изменится чтобы разработчик GLIDE не делал - ничего сломаться не сможет. Вообще никак. То же самое будет если вы подключите её как зависимость указав конкретную версию - пока вы не меняете версию либа ваша не будет иметь проблем. Вы зря опасаетесь этого. Единственное разумное решение в вашей ситуации - использовать сторонние либы. Не надо пилить велосипед.\

Comment: Сломаться может, если пользователь библиотеки подключает в свое приложение тот же Glide, но несовместимой версии... Что ж, наверное вы правы. Спасибо за совет, использую Glide.